# How to force windows mobile to roam between different WiFi access points just like android and PC

Tags: c#, registry, wifi, windows-mobile-6.5, roaming

I have a windows mobile 6.5 professional device that has `PWC` for configuring its WiFi. There is several access points with different SSIDs in my network. This device can connect manually to all of them one by one. I mean the device has saved configuration for all Access points and I can disconnect from one of them and then connect to other one.

I know Roaming Trigger can force WM to Roam between APs with similar SSID and encryption types according to AP quality. But the device can't roam when SSID or encryption type changes. I had another device with `Summit` for configuring its WiFi that could connect to any saved network just like android and laptop.

> Now the question is:
>
> How can I force Windows Mobile 6.5 device to switch between purely different access points just like android and laptop?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The roaming behaviour is defined by the supplicant. The default Microsoft supplicant can roam between different wireless networks and automatically connect to hotspots.

I am knowing about the Odyssey Funk supplicant that it will only allow one connection profile.
The there is a Reliable Access Client that enables the definition of multiple profiles and will switch automatically between these networks.

But I did not yet hear about PWC. If it is an industrial designed supplicant, it may behave like the Odyssey Funk Supplicant and only connect to one defined network.

Normally the OEM will provide an option to switch from there supplied supplicant back to MS ZeroConfig. Did you try this?

If the supplicant only allows one profile it is hard programmming a tool that watches the networks and switches from one to another.